# List-based publish subscribe pattern in c# (Wordpress hooks / filters)

Tags: c#, hook, publish-subscribe, mediator, add-filter

I come from a PHP background and have used **Wordpress** quite a lot, I love how their *plugin architecture* works and the ability to hook events to event names. One of the best parts I like about it is being able to *add_filter()* to any database value just before it gets shown to the end user. My question is multi-part on how to replicate the whole plugin architecture in a C#.NET environment?

**Part 1:**
To create plug-ins I have researched the **MEF framework** would probably be the best (*Managed Extensibility Framework* -http://mef.codeplex.com/). This is designed specifically to take the grunt work out by giving you the ability to monitor directories for new plug-ins, tracking dependencies and other normal things. MEF ships with .NET 3.5+

**Part 2**
Hooking events? I can't seem to find much information about replicating a global channel based event system. From what I have upto yet I need a **publish/subscribe pattern** (which isn't that hard to make as you just create some concrete objects and give them events). The hard part is giving each event a 'channel' name and for all the events in the whole system to be part of a global collection (**Mediator pattern**).

To replicate: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter)

Example 1

```php
// Add's my button to the end of the content
add_filter('the_content', 'my_plugin_button');

function my_plugin_button( $content ) {
    // Add's my button to the end of the content
    return $content . "<a href='#'>My button</a>";
}
```

OR

Example 2

```php
// Add a new admin menu item by hooking in
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_options_page('My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options');
}
```

I hope your all with me upto yet? I have managed to replicate the functionality I need in Javascript and even jQuery has their *.on()* event function... same thing but channel or list based...

My 2 examples:

- http://jsfiddle.net/AaronLayton/U3ucS/53/
- http://jsfiddle.net/AaronLayton/eyNre/33/

Can anyone point me in the correct direction or is this the totaly wrong approach for c#?

Answer (score 0):

I think [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) can help you a lot with these issues. [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/) which is the author of NServiceBus has also written a lot of articles about Domain Event pattern, which is a publish/subscribe mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Espen, however I'm more leaning towards an open-source solution or just a simple replication of the list-based events system. Anyone else with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Know it's been a long time since you posted this and you probably built something already.  However I have been thinking about something like this myself.  There are 2 options - really forget WordPress and try and build something much cleaner - it's a mess at the bottom of WordPress' code :D

Or this:

```
function the_content()
{
        var result = get_the_content();
        // do other stuff...if you want to.
        execute_filters(ref result);
        execute_actions(ref result);

        return result;
}

function execute_filters(ref string result, string action_name)
{
     var filters = get_pre_filters(action_name);
     filters.ForEach(filter =>
     {
         /// somehow call the method name in filter.  PHP is generally global.  C# namespaced,      
         /// so you would need to think about that.
     }
}

function execute_actions(ref string result, string action_name)
{
      /// and so on....
}
```

When building something to mimic WordPress, you need to remember many of the issues of WordPress' plugin architecture (in my personal opinion)... It seems to want to run every plugin near enough on every page even if that page has nothing to do with that plugin.  I onced installed a plugin that added 60 database queries to each page call, and it wasn't used.

Try and think smart about it when you are building it.  Try and add a way to only have the plugins that are going to get used on the page/post of your new setup to be run e.g. in your database have a "Plugins" field on the post/page object with a list of plugins allowed to run on that page.  That way you won't need to check all the plugins each time to see if it wants to run.

Anyways.  Hope you got something working.